# Having trouble with the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: javascript

So I recently discovered this site (https://projecteuler.net). The second problem asks you to find the sum of all even Fibonacci numbers less than four million. I tried to use my limited JavaScript to solve this for me, but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ophunt/pnf24j7q/3/

Here is the javascript contained therein:

```
//variables here
var sum = 0;
var fibA = 1;
var fibB = 1;
var store = 0;

//main loop
while (fibA < 4000000) {
    store = fibA;
    fibA += fibB;
    fibB = store;
    if (fibA % 2 === 0) {
        sum += fibA;
    }
}

Document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sum;
```

Comment: If you checked the error console you'd see that the variable "fib" is not defined.

Comment: You're right, that seems to have helped some. Now the output is "2".

Comment: Well the next step is to get rid of that `setTimeout()` logic - that's why you're getting `2`.  If you take out those two lines (the jQuery call and the `setTimeout()`) and then change the `if` to a `while` (and fix the capital "D" in "document") you'll be all set.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It now works exactly the way it's supposed to. It output 4613732, which was the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a few things can help you out here:

1. The sum up to fibonacci(n) =  fibonacci(n+2) - 1
   This is nice since you don't have to manually do the sums since you are already doing the sums when you create the sequence
2. Even fibonacci numbers are every third fibonacci number. This ends up meaning that the sum of the evens is equal to the sum of all divided by two.

For example:

```
fibs:     1, 1, 2, 3, 5,  8,  13, 21, 34, 55, 89
sums:     1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, 33, 54, 88
even_sum: 0, 0, 2, 2, 2,  10, 10, 10, 44
```

3. Also give a number you can find the which fiboncacci is closest with exceeding it based on some (semi)simple math. (You can also calculate the fibonacci numbers themselves this way, but I'll leave the original function because recursive functions are cool.

The javascript implimentation looks like this:

```
var findFibNum = function(num) {
    var est = Math.log(num * Math.sqrt(5)) /(Math.log((Math.sqrt(5)+1)/2))
    return Math.floor(est)  
}
```

Knowing these three things you can make a pretty quick solution:

```
var top = 4000000;

/* function finds nth fibonacci number */
var fib = function(n){
    if (n <=1) return n;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

/* given a number this finds closest n below it i.e. for 34 it give 9
   because 34 is the nineth fibonacci number
*/
var findFibNum = function(num) {
    var est = Math.log(num * Math.sqrt(5)) /(Math.log((Math.sqrt(5)+1)/2))
    return Math.floor(est)  
}


var n = findFibNum(top) /* fib(n) is the largest fibonacci below top */

/* the sum of fibonacci number n is fib(n)+2 -1 -- this beats looping and adding*/
var fibsum = fib(n+2) -1

/* it s a nice feature of the sequence that the sum of evens is equal to the sum off all dived by 2 */
var evensum = fibsum/2
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0zh9g0h/) gives 4613732

Comment: While that works well for finding a specific Fibonacci term, it doesn't solve the problem initially posed, the sum of all even terms under 4000000. And yes, recursive functions do look a bit scary.

Comment: That will take a *really* long time; it's extremely inefficient.

Comment: Wow, you are much more observant than me. That answer is correct, and the code is quite elegant. It doesn't matter if it's more or less efficient, it only needs to be run once. Thanks for the great response.

Comment: @ophunt you'll find that Project Euler problems are often structured to penalize (or render impossible) the use of an inefficient approach to finding an answer.

Comment: @pointy, there are a lot of algorithms for working out fibonacci numbers. Recursion is slow, but works quickly enough for low values such as these. This seems like a good case for avoiding premature optimization — without too much trouble we could write a matrix exponentiation algorithm in JS, but why if it only saves a few ms?

Comment: @MarkM It's not that recursion is slow. Think about it. You compute Fibonacci number 15. Now it's time to compute Fibonacci number 16. What's the first thing you do? **Recompute Fibonacci number 15.** This is not premature optimization, it's simple algorithmic sense. If what you want to do is generate **all** the Fibonacci numbers, the right thing to do is iterate *upwards* from the pair `1 1`.

Comment: @MarkM (Or, as you added, use the closed-form solution to the problem :)